# Gradle error while trying to build android application using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, gradle, cordova-3

I use cordova to build android apps:

```
$ cordova build android
```

I got an error:

> Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android
> Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include
> gradle in your path, or install Android Studio

Then I tried install gradle:

```
$ sudo apt install gradle
```

And then I'm struggling with this one:

```
aqil@dell:~/hello$ cordova build 

ANDROID_HOME=/home/aqil/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jni/libnative-platform-curses.so: undefined symbol: tgetent
Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 127
```

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with java. Try reinstalling Java maybe.

Comment: what about reinstalling gradle?@Axel

Comment: Since it's an error with Java JNI, it is not neccessary to reinstall Gradle.

Comment: Just found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnative-platform-java/+bug/1683761

Comment: i dont know really what to do,im gonna reinstall java @Axel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally could solve the issue. It was something wrong with the gradle. First step: removing it.

`$ sudo apt remove gradle`

Then i downloaded it manually from the link below

[gradle-3.5.zip](https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip)

Extract then add it's path into the environment using the command below:

```
$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add these two path at the bottom of the file:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/home/aqil/Android/gradle-3.5
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Final step, Tried building but encountered an error:

> BUILD FAILED

> Total time: 9 mins 33.837 secs Error: /home/aqil/App/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'. A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'. Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3. Required by: project :CordovaLib Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3. Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'. Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'. Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

this is network problem. Proxy helped me to bypass network filtering.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Remove Gradle `sudo apt-get remove gradle`
2. Add this to your .bashrc file: `export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-X.XX.X/bin` (Where `X.XX.X` is the version under this path.)

Now `cordova build android` should work without errors.